# split table performance in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

everyone. Here is a problem in my mysql server.
I have a table about 40,000,000 rows and 10 columns.
Its size is about 4GB.And engine is innodb.
It is a master database, and only execute one sql like this.

```
insert into mytable ... on duplicate key update ...
```

And about 99% sqls executed `update` part.

Now the server is becoming slower and slower.
I heard that split table may enhance its performance. Then I tried on my personal computer, splited into 10 tables, failed , also tried 100 ,failed too. The speed became slower instead. So I wonder why splitting tables didn't enhance the performance?

Thanks in advance.

more details:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id BIGINT,
    identifier VARCHAR(64),
    account_id VARCHAR(64),
    top_speed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    total_chars INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    total_time INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    keystrokes  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    avg_speed INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    country_code VARCHAR(16), 
    update_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id), UNIQUE KEY(user_id)
);
```

PS:
I also tried different computers with Solid State Drive and Hard Disk Drive, but didn't help too.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up a table is unlikely to help at all.  Ditto for `PARTITIONing`.

**Let's count the disk hits.**  I will skip counting non-leaf nodes in BTrees; they tend to be cached;  I will count leaf nodes in the data and indexes; they tend not to be cached.

IODKU does:

1. Read the index block containing the for any `UNIQUE` keys.  In your case, that is probably `user_id`.  Please provide a sample SQL statement.  1 read.
2. If the `user_id` entry is found in the index, read the record from the data as indexed by the PK(`id`) and do the `UPDATE`, and leave this second block in the buffer_pool for eventual rewrite to disk.  1 read now, 1 write later.
3. If the record is not found, do `INSERT`.  The index block that needs the new row was already read, so it is ready to have a new entry inserted.  Meanwhile, the "last" block in the table (due to `id` being `AUTO_INCREMENT`) is probably already cached.  Add the new row to it.  0 reads now, 1 write later (`UNIQUE`).  (Rewriting the "last" block is amortized over, say, 100 rows, so I am ignoring it.)
4. Eventually do the write(s).

Total, assuming essentially all take the `UPDATE` path:  2 reads and 1 write.  Assuming the `user_id` follows no simple pattern, I will assume that all 3 I/Os are "random".

**Let's consider a variation...**  What if you got rid of `id`?  Do you need `id` anywhere else?  Since you have a `UNIQUE` key, *it* could be the PK.  That is replace your two indexes with just `PRIMARY KEY(user_id)`.  Now the counts are:

1. 1 read
2. If `UPDATE`, 0 read, 1 write
3. If `INSERT`, 0 read, 0 write

Total:  1 read, 1 write.  2/3 as many as before.  Better, but still not great.

**Caching**

How much RAM do you have?
What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?
`SHOW TABLE STATUS` -- What are `Data_length` and `Index_length`?

I suspect that the buffer_pool is not big enough, and possible could be raised.  If you have more than 4GB of RAM, make it about 70% of RAM.

**Others**

SSDs should have helped significantly, since you appear to be I/O bound.  Can you tell whether you are I/O-bound or CPU-bound?

How many rows are you updating at once?  How long does it take?  Is it batched, or one at a time?  There may be a significant improvement possible here.

Do you really need `BIGINT` (8 bytes)?  `INT UNSIGNED` is only 4 bytes.

Is a transaction involved?

Is the Master having a problem?  The Slave?  Both?  I don't want to fix the Master in such a way that it messes up the Slave.

Comment: Thank you very very much.
I hadn’t considered to delete the auto increment key.That’s fantastic.
1. I tried to change  innodb_buffer_pool_size's value , but didn’t help.
2. I also tried your suggestion , to make the data batched, that is great.
3. BIGINT can not be changed due to the data.
4. And No Transaction involed.
5. Only master have the problem.

Comment: The full sql is like this .   `INSERT DELAYED INTO mytable (user_id, identifier, account_id, top_speed, total_chars, total_time, keystrokes, avg_speed, country_code) VALUES   (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE account_id = %s, top_speed = %s, total_chars = %s, total_time = %s, keystrokes = %s, avg_speed = %s"`

Comment: If replication is "row based", then some of the disk hits happen only in the Master; the Slave does not need to re-decide between insert and update.  This _may_ explain why only the Master is having trouble.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `DELAYED` is an old MyISAM keyword that has no effect (nor any harm) on InnoDB tables.

Comment: Re batching:  If possible, aim for about 100 rows at a time and sort each batch by `user_id`.  Your client API may not have any way to construct a multi-row IODKU, you may have to write some code for that.  (I've done it in PHP; it's not difficult.)

Comment: It is a great idea to make the user_id sorted.Now my strategy is 200 rows at a time with the user_id sorted. And It is committed as a transaction.It is faster.Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your database into some mysql instances using mysql proxy just like mysql-proxy or haproxy instead of one mysql instance. Maybe you can have great performance.

Comment: But my company don't have a lot of budget for more instances.  Is there any way that I can try?Thanks a lot

Comment: you can try to backup some data and delete them if you business is allowed

Comment: or you can split your table into 7 or more table. Read one table one day and backup and clear other tables.

Comment: May be its not good for this situation,it seems to make it more complicated .Thanks for your help.